Authorize.net transaction generated but not displaying in dashboard
I have implement "Create an Accept Payment Transaction" this method for payment. The mail is successfully generating of successful or rejected transaction.
But In Authorize.net dashboard those transactions are not displaying.
I am expecting a transactions record in Authorize.net dashboard.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

I have use "Create an Accept Payment Transaction" this method. The issue I am getting is that I am getting mail of transaction success but  that transaction is not displaying in my Authorize.net Dashboard.
